# Custmized icon for message box

Tags: vbscript

I'm looking for an answer that will describe how to choose your own picture/object and use it as an icon in:

```
x = msgbox ("hey", icon 0,"title")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use custom icons with the VBScript [`MsgBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29) function. You could build a custom dialog using the [Internet Explorer COM object](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_password.php) or an [HTA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx), but that's about all you can do in VBScript.